# C# scale program help(easy)

Tags: c#, math

I'm looking to make a program that calculates the sum of 7 numbers. But with a twist. IF one of these variables is smaller than 84 OR greater than 184, then this one variable is counted out of the sum of the other 6 numbers.

So lets say for example:

```
a=50
b=51
c=90
d=91
e=92
f=93
g=94
```

So now it would be; c+d+e+f+g. Do I need to do this with 1000 "If" sentences?

Comment: No - use a `for` loop or whatever construct fits your language.  It will also be easier if you use a collection rather than 7 variables.

Comment: Not allowed to use for loops yet

Comment: Then I guess you need 7 `if` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to do this with 1000 "If" sentences?

No, just 7

```
int total = 0;
if(a >= 84 && a <= 184)
   total += a;
```

.. etc

Comment: Uh I still don't really understand how to solve this :/

Answer (score 1):

If you are not allowed to use loops then perhaps the next easiest way it to create a function and use that instead of +. I am going to assume then that you are also not allowed to use other slightly more complex concepts like classes ect.

```
public int ValueTest(int iValue)
{
    if ((iValueTwo > 84) && (iValueTwo < 184) {
        return iValue;
    }
    return 0;
}
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    int a=50;
    int b=51;

    int iResult = 0;
    iResult = ValueTest(a) + ValueTest(b);
    Console.WriteLine("Result is: ", iResult);
    return 0;
}
```

I have only done two values but this should give you the idea. Also I haven't tested this code so I may have missed something small but the general idea should still be sound.

Cheers

Comment: Yeah sorry no functions either, I would've done this assigment two days ago if I could use functions or loops :(

Comment: Perhaps you can update your question so that it has more detail about what can and can not be used in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner (or rather a *single statement* formatted to fit here):

```
int total = ((a >= 84 && a <= 184) ? a : 0) + 
        ((b >= 84 && b <= 184) ? b : 0) + 
        ((c >= 84 && c <= 184) ? c : 0) + 
        ((d >= 84 && d <= 184) ? d : 0) + 
        ((e >= 84 && e <= 184) ? e : 0) + 
        ((f >= 84 && f <= 184) ? f : 0) + 
        ((g >= 84 && g <= 184) ? g : 0);
```

Or you could do it with LINQ (if that's allowed):

```
int total = new {a, b, c, d, e, f, g}.Where(x => x >= 84 && x <= 184).Sum();
```

Comment: One-liner spanning multiple lines ;)

Comment: How does your first answer work? I haven't seen this before.

Comment: Oh wait I think I understand, will try this at night and I'll respond how it works out. But what's with the "?"?

Comment: Also how would I go into calculating the average sum of these variables?

Comment: `.Average()` for the LINQ one. For the other, just calculate it: `average = total / n`.

Comment: But if lets say there are only 5 numbers in the correct range, then how would I get the N variable?

Comment: So lets says we have b+c+d+e+f then how would we make the N=5? And If we start the program again and lets say we now have 6 numbers in range so it would be b+c+d+e+f+g then how would the N change to 6? So I could get the average

Comment: In the LINQ case you would use `.Count()` on the filtered list. In the `?.` case you would repeat adding 1 instead of the value, i.e. `int count = ((a >= 84 && a <= 184) ? 1 : 0) + ...`